# How to get a JSON formated snapshot of the current Apex limits with minimal code

Tags: apex, json, governorlimits

I know how to do this technically. Create a class with fields for all Limits and `JSON.serialize` it. But I thought maybe there is a way to get all limits as map an skip the class writing step. I know that the REST API has such an endpoint but doing rest is way to slow for my need. I need an Apex only solution. Too bad that the Limits class is static only, so I can't do a `JSON.serialize(new Limits());`

Comment: Your question title is probably where Mohith was going; if you're looking for per-transaction limits, those are not org limits. There's no equivalent to OrgLimits for the CPU/Query/etc limits found in the Limits namespace.

Answer (score 6):

Spring 19 added [System.OrgLimit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_OrgLimits.htm) class to the System class .You can obtain all the org limits using the below.It does give you a list with name and limit for every limit in the org.

```
List<System.OrgLimit> limits = OrgLimits.getAll();
for (System.OrgLimit aLimit: limits) {
   System.debug('Limit: ' + aLimit.getName());
   System.debug('Max Limit is: ' + aLimit.getLimit());
}
```

There is also a method to return the map

```
Map<String,System.OrgLimit> limitsMap = OrgLimits.getMap();
```

**Update**

The above is for org limits .For current apex context limit since Limit class is a static class unfortunately I cannot think of any other way than creating a map instance and populating or creating an apex class to hold these.

Comment: But that is not for Apex limits only API limits...

Comment: @Robert Could you specify in the question that you need apex context limit ?

Comment: Sure sir! Will do.